# How to give the same name using array in smarty?

Tags: arrays, checkbox, smarty

Following is my code snippet:

```
<tr height="30" id="user_option">
                    <td width="300">
                       <input type="checkbox" id="users" name="users" value="users"/>Users 
                    </td>
                    <td>&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" id="upload_from_file" name="upload_from_file" value="upload_from_file"/>Upload From File
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="copy_paste_from_excel" name="copy_paste_from_excel" value="copy_paste_from_excel"/>Copy paste from excel
                    </td>
                  </tr>
```

This is a code from smarty template. Actually when I submit this form I want an array containing the checkbox values so in order to achieve that I have to use same name for these checkboxes. But I'm not able to name thes checkboxes in such a manner that I could get all the selected checkboxes' value in one single array after form submission. Can you help me in achieving this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the name attribute of checkboxes to be an array:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="id1" name="cb_data[var_name1]" value="some_val"/>
<input type="checkbox" id="id2" name="cb_data[var_name2]" value="another_val"/>
```

then check the `$_POST['cb_data']` array.